# How to show two one label text below other in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uilabel

I want to show text of one label below the other label.Although text should start from right of first label & it should go below the other label.Please tell me it is possible using ios ?

[image]

Comment: I think you would be better off using an `NSAttributedString` and adding a bold attribute to `User`. So your text would be in one UILabel but can have separate font sizes and spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for your question.It is very easy and understandable.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"User this is just a comment.This just a comment.This just a comment."];

NSAttributedString *attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

[mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];

[mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];

labelTextBelowAnotherLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

[labelTextBelowAnotherLabel setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
```

Above in coding i set the helvetica bold and fontsize for reference.If you want to change to systemBold just change and also set the font size according to your requirements.

Thank You-:)

Comment: Whether it works or not tell me.If it works fine give the tick mark and up vote my answer.Because it is so helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

At run time display you use **NSMutableAttributedString**.
e.g.

```
 NSDictionary *dicAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:WHITE_COLOR, NSFontAttributeName: UI_DEFAULT_ROBOTO_BOLD(15.0)};
 NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"here is your text which want to set" attributes:dicAttributes];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible in One label with storyboard.Just use one label and set text as a Attributed.[image]

and select User word and just right click and you find option named as a "**Font**". now you can select as a Bold,Italic,UnderLine etc.

This is easy way to display text in one Label.

It may be helpful to you.

Comment: How do i make it dynamic at run time like the user name fetched from server should be bold

Comment: then you use NSMutableAttributedString to display this.